# jQuery AJAX file upload returning errors, why?

Tags: jquery, ajax, file-upload, image-uploading, jquery-file-upload

When I upload a file to the server, the response is either a number or a boolean, but i'm getting this error:

Object {readyState: 4, responseText: "", status: 200, statusText: "OK"}
abort
:
(a)
always
:
()
catch
:
(a)
done
:
()
fail
:
()
getAllResponseHeaders
:
()
getResponseHeader
:
(a)
overrideMimeType
:
(a)
pipe
:
()
progress
:
()
promise
:
(a)
readyState
:
4
responseText
:
""
setRequestHeader
:
(a,b)
state
:
()
status
:
200
statusCode
:
(a)
statusText
:
"OK"
then
:
(b,d,e)
**proto**
:
Object

my code is this:

```
var btn = $("input[name=submitname]");
            var url = btn.parents("form").attr("action");
                var fileName = btn.parents("form").find("input[type=file]").attr("name");
                var fileVal = btn.parents("form").find("input[type=file]").val();
            var dataString = btn.parents("form").serialize() + "&" + btn.attr("name") + "=" + btn.val() + "&" + fileName + "=" + fileVal;
                $.ajax({
                    url: url,
                    type: "POST", 
                    data: dataString, 
                    processData: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(data){
                        console.log(data);
                    }, error: function(errData){
                        console.log(url);
                        console.log(dataString);
                        console.log("error:");
                        console.log(errData);
                    }
                });
```

When I use almost the same code (without processData, contentType and cache) for other forms which don't have files it works, but with files (images) i always get the above error. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: What `error`???

Comment: @GuruprasadRao Object {readyState: 4, responseText: "", status: 200, statusText: "OK"} in the console when I do console.log(errData)

Comment: That's not `error`.. `status:200` and `statusText:"Ok"` always means, the request has been `success`..

Comment: @GuruprasadRao it comes from the ajax error function so whatever it didn't work, i call that an error

Comment: I don't think so.. Cos you have `console.log(data)` in `success` too.. Make sure what `console.log` is getting printed and am sure that this is from success, cos only request is success, the above message comes..

Comment: do you realize you are not uploading the file you select?

Comment: @GuruprasadRao i have console.log("error") in the error function and not in the success function so i do know which one it's returning...

Comment: @epascarello nope, i did not realize that because the ajax function has everything in it that my research has told me it needs so i don't see why it wouldn't be uploading... did i miss something?